# Error: Unrecognized object type. with stargazer function in R

Tags: r, stargazer

Could someone please help me in understanding why I get this error with the stargazer function in R?

For example: This is my dataset "M1" where CSR spent is the independent variable and PR1 is the dependent variable.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bKA2t.png)

library(stargazer)
library(pacman)
p_load(data.table,fixest,magrittr,sandwich)
library(fixest)

#Regression model
M1a = feols(CSRspent~PR1,data=M1)
summary(M1a)
stargazer(M1a, type= 'text', title= 'Table 2: CSR spent and PR1 without controls')

% Error: Unrecognized object type.

Intended output:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kkzq1.png)

Does stargazer not run on `fixest` object?

Comment: You should post something reproducible, and then we could figure out where the error message is coming from.

Comment: Welcome to SO, Aishwarya Narayanan! Questions on SO (especially in R) do much better if they are reproducible and self-contained. By that I mean including attempted code (please be explicit about non-base packages), sample representative data (perhaps via `dput(head(x))` or building data programmatically (e.g., `data.frame(...)`), possibly stochastically), perhaps actual output (with verbatim errors/warnings) versus intended output. Refs: https://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269, [mcve], and https://stackoverflow.com/tags/r/info.

Comment: I have added the example of dataset as well as the libraries that I have used. Also included the intended output for your reference.